# Carregar o site todo ao entrar

Tags: html

Boas eu gostava de saber se era possivel ao entrar na minha website, a mesma ser logo toda carregada na cache, para durante o navegamento da mesma não haver aqueles tempos mortos onde a pagina esta a carregar a informação. Obrigado

Comment: Se o teu website tem páginas diferentes o mais que podes fazer é melhorar as páginas para ficarem mais leves. Se tiveres o site todo numa página só isso já acontece. Acho difícil conseguirmos responder a esta pergunta.

Comment: com includes isso melhora?

Answer (score 1):

É possível que você utilize o cache de aplicação para guardar os arquivos que são comumente acessados em suas páginas, como imagens, arquivos de estilo e scripts. Isso diminuirá bastante o que você considera como "tempo morto".

Poderia explicar diretamente aqui como usar e restringir o cache de aplicação, mas por ser um assunto extenso e ter bastante conteúdo sobre na internet, vou apenas indicar algumas leituras para seu estudo e uso:

http://www.html5rocks.com/pt/tutorials/appcache/beginner

http://sergiolopes.org/palestra-appcache-html5-offline

A vantagem de ter maestria sobre esse tipo de tecnologia, é criar uma aplicação que possa ser acessada inclusive quando o usuário não tiver acesso a internet.